# How to cancel one particular task out of N number of tasks?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I've N number of tasks with its own CancellationTokenSource. To track each task and its CancellationTokenSource, I'm using ConcurrentDictionary. So that whenever I need to cancel a particular task, I get the CancellationTokenSource of that task from ConcurrentDictionary and cancel it.

The problem is whenever I cancel one task all other tasks also get cancelled. Is there anything I'm missing here or any other better implementation than this. Sample code below.

```
CancellationTokenSource _serviceCancelSource;
public async Task Start()
{    
    var services = _serviceRepository.GetAll();
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(services, x => Task.Run(() => Start(x)));
    });           
}

public async Task Start(Service service)
{
    _serviceCancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    myConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate(service.Id, _serviceCancelSource, (key, oldValue) => _serviceCancelSource));
    var manager = ServiceManagerFactory.Create(service);
    Action serviceAction = () => manager.InitializeTaskAsync();
    await Task.Run(() =>  PeriodicTaskFactory.Start(serviceAction, intervalInMilliseconds: service.PollTime, cancelToken: _serviceCancelSource.Token, serviceName: service.ServiceName));
}

public async Task CancelTask()
{    
    await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var serviceId = GetChangedService();
                CancellationTokenSource cancelSource;
                if (myConcurrentDictionary.TryGetValue(serviceId, out cancelSource))
                {
                    cancelSource.Cancel();                                               
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Why do you store cancellation token in `myConcurrentDictionary` but then search for it in `DataService.serviceCancellationTokenMap`? And why you don't specify a type for `serviceCancelSource` within the `Start` method? Is it a field in the class? In general - there's no way to reproduce the issue using the code that you've provided.

Comment: @SergeyShevchenko My bad. I modified the original code to put the sample here and missed some places. I've edited the code. And you are right about _serviceCancelSource, its a field in the class.

Comment: Not sure if I read your code correctly, but if you're sharing the token source, then it will cancel all tokens, hence all tasks that receive a token from that source. You need to not share the token source. But again, I'm not sure enough from reading your code to make this an answer.

Comment: @Kit Every time I'm adding new token source to the dictionary for each service. so it is not shared.

Comment: @Raj I guess my confusion is because of `_serviceCancelSource` and `serviceCancelSource`. Why do you need the former field when you have sources stored in the dictionary?

Comment: @Kit _serviceCancelSource is for creating new object of CancellationTokenSource for each service task and added to the dictionary. cancelSource (Name changed to avoid confusion) is used to get the CancellationTokenSource  FROM the dictionary using serviceId. Then call the cancel function to cancel that specific service task.

Comment: @Raj: Please post a [minimal, complete example that reproduces the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's almost impossible to guess what the problem could be when we only have partial code that has been modified.

Comment: @StephenCleary Sorry about how I presented the problem. The issue is fixed by using local variable for CancellationTokenSource instead of using a field. Next time I'll do better. Your posts and blogs are really helping me to learn TPL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I see with the code is the shared variable “_serviceCancelSource.”

The Parallel.Foreach in the code above will call the "Start(service)" method parallely on multiple threads and hence the statement “_serviceCancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();” gets executed almost simultaneously on all the threads.
Remember that "_serviceCancelSource" is a variable that is shared across all threads.

By the time the control reaches "myConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate()", (which probably has some locking mechanism for thread safety), the shared variable “_serviceCancelSource” has a value from the thread that finished last.

As a result, the concurrent dictionary ends up having the same CancellationTokenSource instance for all the "Service.ids" which could be the reason why canceling one task cancels all your other tasks.

Could you please let us know the outcome if you were to assign the new cancellation token to a local variable and then add it to the concurrent dictionary.

Comment: I removed the field, added local variable and now I'm able to cancel any specific task from the dictionary. Thank you Praveen for saving my day. As I'm a newbie, I'm not able to close this as the answer.